# Magento Error - missing class when accessing cart page?

Tags: magento

After upgrading to Magento Community 1.6.1.0 (stable) whenever I try and access the cart page, I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Checkout_Block_Multishipping_Link' not found in /data01/director/public_html/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 465
```

If you google the first part of the error a number of other sites appear sporting the same error, but there is no mention of any solution.

Help?

The Layout.php file hasn't been changed (tried re-uploading the original file)

Comment: Oh and the problem persists regardless of which theme I use. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I had tried emptying caches, deleting browser cookies, different browsers, different themes and so on with no luck. In the end, re-uploading the 1.6.1.0 files did the trick (even though I hadn't modified any files outside the theming directories).

Hope this is useful for someone.